# Enable Xcode debugging on jailbroken iOS 8.4 device

Tags: iphone, xcode, jailbreak

I want to develop with Xcode 6.4 on iOS 8.4 devices without a developer account.
I did Taig jailbreak on my iPad mini retina 2 and followed this guide:

[How to debug iOS apps in a jailbroken device with xcode 6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913239/how-to-debug-ios-apps-in-a-jailbroken-device-with-xcode-6-2)

I modified the SDKSettings.plist file with the following values:

ENTITLEMENTS_REQUIRED to YES
 CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED to NO
 AD_HOC_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED to YES

I can install the app on the device but the debug does not work (the app crash on the device when launched from Xcode).
To enable the debug I add the Entitlements.plist file (with "Can be debugged" to "YES") to my project and trying to execute I get the following message:

"App installation failed
The application could not be verified."

I missed something? 
Everyone has the debug working on iOS 8.4 with Xcode 6.4?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add to the Entitlements.plist:
"application-identifier" and 
string value: "$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)" (both without quotes).

If it does not work you can check the log ([Apple iOS Device logging](https://www.sophos.com/de-de/support/knowledgebase/113906.aspx))

EDIT: I am able to run my app on iOs 8.4 with this scenario